# Find the smallest value in an array excluding 0

Tags: arrays, scala, vector

I have an array like:

```
val a = Array(0, 6, 15, 0, 20, 0)
```

if I use the `reduceLeft` function for finding the smallest value in this array, something like:

```
val f = (x: Int, y: Int) => x min y
val rlf = a.reduceLeft(f)
```

how I can find the smallest number in this array excluding the comparison with `0`, because in my case I am using `0` as a default value not as something that I want to compare with?!

Comment: Is your array guaranteed to be non-empty? What do you want to return if the array contains just 0?

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn , yes, the array is  guaranteed to be nonempty. If all the values are 0 then I can accept to get a `-1` value - it may not scale but for the moment I will simplify it so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Origin:**

```
scala> val a = Array(0, 6, 15, 0, 20, 0)
a: Array[Int] = Array(0, 6, 15, 0, 20, 0)

scala> a.filterNot(_==0).min
res6: Int = 6
```

**Update:**
I missed case with empty array after filter. So correct version is like

```
a.filterNot(_==0) match {
  case Array() => -1
  case arr => arr.min
}
```

or

```
Try(a.filterNot(_==0).min).getOrElse(-1)
```

**Update:**
To get min with index:

```
Try(a.zipWithIndex.filterNot(_._1 == 0).minBy(_._1)).getOrElse((-1,-1))
```

Or

```
a.zipWithIndex.filterNot(_._1==0) match {
  case Array() => (-1,-1)
  case arr => arr.minBy(_._1)
}
```

or (@Ryan solution with one iteration over array)

```
a.foldLeft((-1, -1, 0)) {
  case ((min, minInd, length), n) =>
    if (n == 0) (min, minInd, length + 1)
    else if (min > -1) {
      val localMin = Math.min(min, n)
      (localMin, if (localMin == min) minInd else length, length + 1)
    }
    else (n, length, length + 1)
}
```

it's maybe much more pretty to use "classical" cycle for optimized solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It's what I was trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: using this method to get the smallest element in the Array, is there a possibility to get the index of that element also?

Comment: I have this solution: 
 `val min_val = a.filterNot(_ == 0) match {
      case Array() => -1
      case arr => a.indexOf(arr.min)
    }`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one pass with a `foldLeft`, which will also handle the empty case:

```
a.foldLeft(-1) { (min, n) => 
  if (n == 0) 
    min 
  else if (min > -1) 
    Math.min(min, n) 
  else 
    n 
}
```

Start with -1.  If `n` is 0, use the previous minimum.  If the previous minimum is greater than -1, take the min of the previous minimum and `n`.  Otherwise (and this is just the first non-zero `n`), `n` is the new minimum.

`foldLeft` is safe to use on an empty collection because you are providing a default value.  If you have an empty array, `foldLeft` will just return -1 in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan for this alternative solution. It's really great.